# Can bandwidth of the closed loop be bigger than bandwidth of individual elements in it?

Tags: control-systems, bandwidth

This is a question from control theory but I hope you can help me with it. I was pointed to this community.

So in my control loop I have elements that have cut-off frequency of 3-5kHz and I designed a PID controller for the inner loop and those elements and suddenly I get a closed loop bandwidth of 30-50kHz cut-off frequency.

So the loop is in the figure bellow.[image: Closed control loop]

So the PID controller, or voltage controller I designed is a PID with a derivative filter. Current sources are modeled as 1st order filters with 3-5kHz cutoff frequency. How is it possible to get such a high bandwidth of the closed loop if the inner elements have a lower cut-off frequency?

Thanks

Comment: How are you measuring the bandwidth? What do you mean by "suddenly"? Are there any non-linear elements?

Comment: I assume your last question should read `How is it possible to get such a high bandwidth of the **CLOSED** loop if the inner elements have a lower cut-off frequency?`

Comment: @MBaz I plotted the closed loop response in Matlab and I simulated the same thing in Simulink. By "suddenly" I mean that I'm surprised to get such a huge bandwidth.

Comment: @PeterK. Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Use MATLAB commands to examine the frequency domain behaviour of the closed loop system. Explain the differences between the theoretical values for Bode diagrams and the simulated results.

Comment: negative feedback on 2nd-order systems normally increases bandwidth, however it's defined.  this system appears to be more than 2nd-order.

Comment: @MichalisChristodoulou I still can't test the controller but I should be able to do it in the next few weeks. I have a feeling it won't work in practice because of the feedback current source cut-off frequency. I don't see how a 30kHz Vout signal could pass through this "filter" but we'll see.

Comment: @robertbristow-Johnson Indeed, this system is 2nd order in numerator and 4th in denominator, however because of the zeros and poles positions it can be as a 3rd order in denominator.

Comment: well, sometimes negative feedback in 3rd-order or higher causes them to oscillate.  oscillation is definitely narrowing the bandwidth to the point of a single frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly possible and to be expected.

Below is a toy example that starts with a Butterworth low pass filter and puts it in the forward path of a feedback loop. The feedback path has a gain of two.

This makes the whole loop unstable, but it also makes the bandwidth very high.

The original filter's frequency response is below.

[image]

And this is the closed loop response.

### [image]

**R Code Below**
    #30035

```
library("signal")

bf <- butter(5, 0.1)
freqz(bf)
dev.copy(png, 'Q30035/Q30035-Butterworth.png')
dev.off()

k <- 2
bf2 <- bf
bf2$a <- bf$a + k*bf$b
bf2$b <- bf$a*k
freqz(bf2)
dev.copy(png, 'Q30035/Q30035-Feedback.png')
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi, I have one more question. How can I decrease the bandwith? I'd like the cutoff frequency to be at 3kHz for example.

Comment: @MarkoP Usually lowering the overall gain of a controller decreases the bandwidth.